# What's the best method to quickly convert a list of numbers into a mysql IN list?

Tags: mysql, excel

When building a query and and I have a large amount of numbers to put in, I'll use an `IN` clause. I'm usually pulling in these numbers from Excel.

At the moment I'm using `=CONCAT(A1,B1,C1,D1)` in Excel, in the following format:

```
'12345','12345',
```

This gives me the output that I need to paste into my query.

I can't help but think there is a better way of doing this though! What methods do you use to achieve the same result? I'm always looking at ways optimise.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I've found is to save the spreadsheet as a 'csv' file, and adjust the options to suit:

- Set all cells to be 'quoted' by apostrophes
- if your values are entered vertically, set the row terminator as a comma

Save it, then re-open it in a text editor like Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I use a "helper" column adjacent to the data with formula like:-

```
="'"&A1&"',"
```

Copy the formula down to the end of the used areas of the column. Select the new column cells and paste into your script, then just remove the trailing comma and wrap it in brackets `()`